# Is it illegal to upload a movie on facebook and allow only one friend to see it

Tags: copyright, legal-terms

I believe that it is perfectly legal to buy a movie and watch it at home with a friend. So considering this logic I was thinking about uploading a movie to Facebook as a post and allow only that friend to see it. Note that I cannot send him that movie as a private message attached file as there is a file size limit of 25 Mb.

So is it illegal?

Comment: Just in case there is any doubt, my friend is a good friend and he won't take the video to police.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally illegal: this is copyright infringement. It is not relevant whether people who watch the movie with you are your friends; it does not matter whether you might get away with illegally uploading a file for just one friend to watch, or thousands of friends. Any complete copying without permission is copyright infringement. Same with copying 50% of a movie, or 10%, etc. It would als be illegal to email the movie, even if there were no file-size limit.